# What is the best way to overwrite a Python Class __str__ method?

Tags: python, class, datetime, inheritance

In my app, I want all my `datetime.__str__()` to return differently to the default.  Is it ok to simply inherit and overwrite the method?

```
class datetime(datetime):
    def __str__(self):
        return self.strftime('%d-%m-%y %H:%M:%S')
```

Any advice would be great.

Comment: It is not a good practice naming a class with lowercase letters only. Take a look at the Python style guide: python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names

Comment: Yeah, that's basically how things work in OOP. Note however, that your class will no longer be returning a string in ISO 8601 format, which could at least in theory cause a problem somewhere else -- for instance if you passed an instance of your class to a routine that was expecting a regular `datatime` object. It might be better to just use the existing `strftime(format)` method directly.

Comment: @Eric That's the first thing I did.  My question is whether its "ok", not so much "this doesn't work".  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, you will want to name your new class something other than one defined in the builtin modules, but yes, that is how you do it.  Please for the sake of your sanity do not create a class definition using the same name as a predefined class.

I just tried to do the `class datetime(datetime)` bit, and it does work, at least in the interpreter, but any python expert will probably laugh or shudder.

Comment: haha, yeah, I think you're right.  It will probably bite me at some point.  I'll go for a different name.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's quite a philosophical question :) Generally in Python we don't like such things. 
You now must use your own class and always remember to use it instead of default datetime (which is hard to maintain if they have the same name). Ruby guys would just monekypatch datetime, which I consider even worse.

I would personally not even inherit it with different name (it would be confusing me also), but make some shortcut function outside any class and use it directly.